# Why does XCTest save a ton of data to my /private/vars/folders/rx/ folder?

Tags: xcode, macos, xctest

I'm using XCtest with XCode 6.3 to test an app of mine.  I've noticed that it seems to be saving a ton of data to my `/private/vars/folders/rx/` folder.  If I delete my app's Derived Data these XCTest folders don't get deleted, and if I restart my computer it's still there too.  Is this data safe to delete or do I need it?

I used DaisyDisk (awesome program by the way!) to take a look at my computer's memory and I see this:

[image]

So I thought I'd take a look at what was in each of these folders.  When I looked, it seemed like XCTest was the culprit.

[image]

When running my tests I include a large bundle of jpgs that is around 1.7 GB.  I'm working on streamlining my app testing so that I don't need the large bundle, but I'm still curious if I can safely delete some of these older folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are safe to delete. This is where Xcode stores built copies of your applications when built in "Unit Test" mode. Just as Xcode has a `Derived Data` folder for building OS X apps, it has another location for storing XCTest data (storing this data in the `Derived Data` folder wouldn't be appropriate, since that is used to store built copies of the application intended to be run by the user).

You should note, though, that Xcode will probably put the data back there again the next time you try to run your app's unit tests, and it may take longer to build/run since some of the cached data is gone. It's up to you whether the trade-off is worth it.

And by the way, Xcode builds your entire project to run XCTest, because your tests might depend on certain resources being there in your app bundle. So that's why the folder is so large.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I just deleted most of the 29 GBs XCTest put on my hard drive and my tests are still running just fine.  Strange that there isn't a "Delete Derived Data" option equivalent for XCTest since this data sure built up fast.  I'll get to optimizing my bundle ASAP